# Invoke class in another class

Tags: java, selenium, invoke

I am working on a project to test a website automatic with selenium. This is my main class that i want to run:

```
package Login;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test{

WebDriver driver;
String baseUrl;

private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Test
@Parameters("browser")
public void LoginDebiteurVerkeerdPage(String browserName) {

    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\cursus\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\cursus\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\cursus\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    baseUrl = "https://www.l.nl/";
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");

    // Testscases
    Here i wanna invoke a few testcases that are in other classes.

    // For example: LoginLogout (class LoginLogout)
    // For example: LoginWrongusername (class LoginWrongusername)
    // For example: LoginWrongpassword (class Loginwrongpassword)

    driver.close();
}

}
```

I want to have the testcases in an other class so it will be structured and maintainable.

How can i invoke these classes (which my test cases are) in my "Test" class?

Thanks,
Piet

Answer (score 0):

You could define some static method inside any of those classes you want to execute in Test and add all scenarios on it. For example.

```
public class LoginLogout (){

    public static executeScenarios(Driver driver){
        //your code here
    }
}
```

In your Test class:

```
LoginLogout.executeScenarios(driver);
LoginWrongusername.executeScenarios(driver); 
...
```

Even you could make that all yours classes with the scenarios extends from a common class where the driver is initialized, and the you only have to pass the browser to the method.

Hope it helps you